# OpenCV does not install Python support correctly

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install OpenCV with Python-Support on Ubuntu 16.04. I am following this tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/
I'm stuck at Step #4, the cmake build. As instructed, I'm using

```
 cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

There's no error messages, but the output does not look correct. According to the tutorial, it should look like

[image]

Mine looks like this (I created the virtual environment with python3):

[image]

Where are the libraries and packages and numpy lines? The folder `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` is empty. In the virtual environment I tried running python3 and then `import cv2`, the output is `ImportError: No module named 'cv2'`. I should add that this is already the third or fourth attempt of installing OpenCV which might have f'ed things up on the file system, I have no idea. I just want this to be over...

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the whole folder once more and tried again, this time libraries etc were set. What I THINK happened the time before is that I did not install numpy in the virtual environment.